# Function to split 2D array for use in train_test_split() error ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, train-test-split

Hi guys I don't know why this function is not working as expected. Any guidance would be appreciated. I get error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Write a function that will take as input a 2-d numpy array and return four variables in the form of `(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)`, where `(X_train, y_train)` are the features + response of the training set, and `(X-test, y_test)` are the features + response of the testing set.

***Function Specifications:***

- Should take a 2-d numpy `array` as input.
- Should split the array such that X is the year, and y is the corresponding population.
- Should return two `tuples` of the form `(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)`.
- Should use sklearn's train_test_split function with a `test_size = 0.2` and `random_state = 42`.

Numpy array input:

```
array([[  1960,  54211],
       [  1961,  55438],
       [  1962,  56225],
       [  1963,  56695],
       [  1964,  57032],
       [  1965,  57360],
       [  1966,  57715],
       [  1967,  58055],
       [  1968,  58386],
       [  1969,  58726],
       [  1970,  59063],
       [  1971,  59440]...
```

My function:

```
    def feature_response_split(arr):
        X, y = np.split(arr, 2, axis=1)
        (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 42)
        return (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test)
```

Input code: (Not changeable)

```
data = get_year_pop('Aruba')
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = feature_response_split(data)
```

Expected output:

```
X_train == array([1996, 1991, 1968, 1977, 1966, 1964, 2001, 1979, 1990, 2009, 2010,
       2014, 1975, 1969, 1987, 1986, 1976, 1984, 1993, 2015, 2000, 1971,
       1992, 2016, 2003, 1989, 2013, 1961, 1981, 1962, 2005, 1999, 1995,
       1983, 2007, 1970, 1982, 1978, 2017, 1980, 1967, 2002, 1974, 1988,
       2011, 1998])

y_train == array([ 83200,  64622,  58386,  60366,  57715,  57032,  92898,  59980,
        62149, 101453, 101669, 103795,  60657,  58726,  61833,  62644,
        60586,  62836,  72504, 104341,  90853,  59440,  68235, 104822,
        97017,  61032, 103187,  55438,  60567,  56225, 100031,  89005,
        80324,  62201, 101220,  59063,  61345,  60103, 105264,  60096,
        58055,  94992,  60528,  61079, 102053,  87277])

X_test == array([1960, 1965, 1994, 1973, 2004, 2012, 1997, 1985, 2006, 1972, 2008,
       1963])

y_test == array([ 54211,  57360,  76700,  60243,  98737, 102577,  85451,  63026,
       100832,  59840, 101353,  56695])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect:

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = train_test_split(X, y, ...)
```

Accoring to the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) it should be

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, ...)
```